# Is there a way to quickly add a new row of fields on a visulforce page?

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce, apex

I am trying to create a incident log in safesfore. The key aspect is that everything can be added on the same page reducing the amount of clicks that have to be made. There are 6 fields i have created:

Date Opened, Date closed, incident, reported to, reported by and notes.

I was wondering if there is a way to create an "add new" button that will create another row of the fields i have just lised. The idea being that the page does not refresh it is all done in real time.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a custom Visualforce page implementation.
There are 2 ways to do it

1) Building a list of records on apex and iterate over that list displaying the fields on the front end (vf page apex:repeat)-- Then when the button "add new" is clicked you'll append an empty record to the list and re-render the apex:repeat to reflect the changes. 
This is good because you don't need a lot of boilerplate code since the records with be binded with the backend. However, the rerendering can lead to some performance issues in my experience.

2) Build a custom Javascript implementation, where you have an in memory collection and using DOM manipulation add/remove rows of the list. When the user saves the data from memory must be sent using JSON and a VF Remoting method can perform the JSON parsing and saving the rows.

Both are valid, the first is good to avoid boilerplate but the second is much faster (but you need to write some boilerplate).